# Compiling Scheme to Java and/or Objective-C

Tags: cross-platform, scheme

We have [Bigloo.NET](http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Manuel.Serrano/publi/jot04/jot04.html) does anyone know of such a project that offers the same but for the Java and/or Objective-C language?

I am developing a component of a project that will also have a Windows and Apple GUI built around it. Would be nice if I could develop this component in a single language and have it compiled into the native language for the current GUI. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Do you know that Bigloo initially targeted the JVM, and only later the CLR?  I'm assuming you do, and that it's insufficient for you.  If you weren't aware:

> Java code and Bigloo code can be
>   merged together. Bigloo functions can
>   call Java functions and vice-versa,
>   Bigloo code can use and instantiate
>   Java classes. Bigloo functions and
>   variables can hold Java values (Java
>   classes values). Bigloo data
>   structures can point to Java data
>   structures and vice-versa.

If that doesn't do it for you, but you still want a Lisp, [Clojure](http://clojure.org) is a Lisp, though neither Scheme nor Common Lisp.  It shares with Scheme a single namespace for functions and variables, however, and I've found it pretty comfortable in my short acquaintance with it.  Clojure is also Java --- anything you do from Clojure can be used from plain Java, and vice versa.

Maybe you could give more detail on why Bigloo doesn't work for you, and that could help us give better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Schemes for the JVM: [SISC](http://sisc-scheme.org/) and [JScheme](http://jscheme.sourceforge.net/jscheme/main.html). Both are interpreters with good Java interoperability.